# Counting first letter of string and showing how many times it appears, but not in alphabetical order in R

Tags: r, string, count, strsplit, preserve

I currently have this code written to count how many times the first letter of a code appears in a specific column in a table.

```
#a test data frame    
test <- data.frame("State" = c("PA", "RI", "SC"), "Code1" = c("EFGG, AFGG", "SSAG", "AFGG, SSAG"))

#code to count method codes
test[] <- lapply(test, as.character)


test_counts <- sapply(strsplit(test$Code1, ",\\s+"), function(x) {
  tab <- table(substr(x, 1, 1)) # Create a table of the first letters
  paste0(names(tab), tab, collapse = ", ") # Paste together the letter w/ the number and collapse 
them
} )

#example of output
[1] "A1, E1" "S1"     "A1, S1"
```

Everything about this current code is perfect, except I would like R to not output the counts in alphabetical order. I would like it to preserve the order of codes. So this is how I would like the output to look:

```
 [1] "E1, A1", "S1", "A1, S1"
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `factor` to address the issue

```
sapply(
  strsplit(test$Code1, ", "),
  function(x) {
    toString(
      do.call(
        paste0,
        rev(stack(table(factor(u<-substr(x, 1, 1),levels = unique(u)))))
      )
    )
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "E1, A1" "S1"     "A1, S1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `tidyverse`.  We could split the 'Code1' with `separate_rows`, get the `count` and do a `group_by` `paste` after `arrange`ing the rows based on the frequency column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
    separate_rows(Code1) %>%
    mutate(Code1 = substr(Code1, 1, 1)) %>%
    count(State, Code1) %>% 
    arrange(State, n) %>% 
    unite(Code1, Code1, n, sep="") %>% 
    group_by(State) %>% 
    summarise(Code1 = toString(Code1), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    pull(Code1)
#[1] "A1, E1" "S1"     "A1, S1"
```